# idea of attractive

Tags: grammar

This is an excerpt from [a Vox article](https://www.vox.com/the-goods/22894810/best-money-bdsm-whip-marriage).

> I wasn’t interested in looking like my husband’s increasingly
> exaggerated **idea of attractive**, and he wasn’t interested in intimacy,
> touch, or plain old nakedness.

Can the adjective *attractive* be the object of the preposition *of*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is natural, but I would put "attractive" in quotes, like in this similar headline:

> Why your idea of 'old' changes as you age — [Star Advertiser](https://www.staradvertiser.com/2019/09/03/live-well/why-your-idea-of-old-changes-as-you-age/)

The expression "idea of" is most often used with a plain old noun. However, it's also very often used with a quoted expression. That works because when you're [mentioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) an expression, it gets treated like a noun in the sentence.

Here's an example of a longer mentioned phrase:

> For someone who doesn't have a clear idea of "I want to be X by Y time", and just wants to work a bit, exploring options, it would be much more beneficial to ditch grad school. — [100 Reasons NOT to Go to Graduate School](http://100rsns.blogspot.com/2012/09/86-it-is-state-of-being.html?m=1)

Comment: +1 for bringing up the quotation marks and how that draws the use/mention distinction into the discussion. For a clearer example, use "beauty"/"beautiful" instead: "my husband's idea of beautiful" sounds incorrect, while "my husband's idea of *beautiful*" is acceptable and "my husband's idea of beauty" is probably the most correct.